# How to implement a coroutine for applicative computations?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, functor, applicative

Here is a coroutine that avoids nested patterns like (`chain(m) (chain(...))` for monadic computations:

```js
const some = x => none => some => some(x);
const none = none => some => none;

const option = none => some => tx => tx(none) (some);
const id = x => x;

const of = some;
const chain = fm => m => none => some => m(none) (x => fm(x) (none) (some));

const doM = (chain, of) => gf => {
  const it = gf();

  const loop = ({done, value}) =>
    done
      ? of(value)
      : chain(x => loop(it.next(x))) (value);

  return loop(it.next());
};

const tx = some(4),
  ty = some(5),
  tz = none;

const data = doM(chain, of) (function*() {
  const x = yield tx,
    y = yield ty,
    z = yield tz;

  return x + y + z;
});

console.log(
  option(0) (id) (data)); // 0
```

But I'm not able to implement an equivalent coroutine for applicative computations:

```js
const some = x => none => some => some(x);
const none = none => some => none;

const option = none => some => tx => tx(none) (some);
const id = x => x;

const of = some;
const map = f => t => none => some => t(none) (x => some(f(x)));
const ap = tf => t => none => some => tf(none) (f => t(none) (x => some(f(x))));

const doA = (ap, of) => gf => {
  const it = gf();

  const loop = ({done, value}, initial) =>
    done
      ? value
      : ap(of(x => loop(it.next(x)))) (value);

  return loop(it.next());
};

const tx = some(4),
  ty = some(5),
  tz = none;

const data = doA(ap, of) (function*() {
  const x = yield tx,
    y = yield ty,
    z = yield tz;

  return x + y + z;
});

console.log(
  option(0) (id) (data)); // none => some => ...
```

This should work, but it doesn't. Where does the additional functorial wrapping come from? I guess I am a bit lost in recursion here.

By the way I know that this only works for deterministic functors/monads.

Comment: What is the expected result? `0`?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes. In this contrived example monadic and applicative computations are interchangeable.

Comment: `js:21 Uncaught TypeError: some is not a function;`

Comment: To mimic Haskell's `do` notation, you might want to have the generator's return value be of the monadic type, instead of wrapping it with `of`.

Comment: @Bergi I thought it was more convenient to just allow returning the bare value...

Comment: in `doA`, `loop` always returns an applicative, and `ap` wraps the result in `some(f(x))`. The type of `ap` is `(M a -> b) -> M a -> M b` but the way you're lifting `loop` results in `(M a -> M b)` so the final result is `M (M b)`, instead of the intended `M b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not able to implement an equivalent coroutine for applicative computations

Yes, because generator functions are monadic, not just applicative. The operand of a `yield` expression can depend on the result of the previous `yield` expression - that's characteristic for a monad.

> Where does the additional functorial wrapping come from? I guess I am a bit lost here.

You are doing `ap(of(…))(…)` - this is equivalent to `map(…)(…)` according to the [Applicative laws](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative). Compared to the `chain` call in the first snippet, this does not do any unwrapping of the result, so you get a nested `maybe` type (which in your implementation, is encoded as a function).

Comment: _Yes, because generator functions are monadic, not applicative._ I totally missed that, thanks!

Comment: On second thought this part of your answer is a bit misleading, because monad is applicative + it can depend on the value of a previous monadic computation. So when you say generators are monadic, you implicitly state they are applicative as well.